# OPENROWSET Bulk insert Text File NULL Columns

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017, bcp, openrowset

I need to automate a weekly import of .txt log files into a SQL database. I have already created my table, format file and can get some of the data to work using OPENROWSET BULK, but the data from the log files is not consistent.

The table has 10 columns 9 of which are populated from the log file, last 3 columns are all descriptions but the log file may only have a single description column populated (the max is always 3).

In the image below the highlighted rows work because they have the valid 3 column worth of data separated by a comma. Is there a way to force BCP to always populate the 3 columns or mark them as NULL then move onto the next row?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a combination of Power Shell and SQL, PS cleans the files first, adds the correct headers and formatting combined with a format file I have been able to get this to work and it is reliable.

If anyone does have any thoughts or suggestions please post them.